# Processing outputs of multiple inputs in C

Tags: c, string

It's not something trivial but I would like to know the best way to process multiple outputs, for example:

Input

First line of input will contain a number T = number of test cases. Following lines will contain a string each.

Output

For each string, print on a single line, "UNIQUE" - if the characters are all unique, else print "NOT UNIQUE"

Sample Input

```
 3
 DELHI
 london
 #include<iostream>
```

Sample Output

```
 UNIQUE
 NOT UNIQUE
 NOT UNIQUE
```

So how can I accomplish outputs like that? My code so far is:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
 {

     int inputs, count=0;
     char str[100];
     char *ptr;

     scanf("%d",&inputs);


     while(inputs-- >0)
     {
         scanf("%s",str);

         for(ptr=str; *ptr!='\0';ptr++)
         {
             if( *ptr== *(ptr+1))
             {
                 count++;
             }
         }
         if(count>0)
         {
             printf("NOT UNIQUE");

         }
         else
         {
             printf("UNIQUE");
         }

     }

 }
```

But the above will obviously print the output after each input, but I want the output only after entering all the inputs, if the user enters 3, then the user have to give 3 strings and after the output will be given whether the given strings are unique or not. So I want to know how can I achieve the result given in the problem. Also another thing I want to know is, I am using an array of 100 char, which it can hold a string up to 100 characters, but what do I have to do if I want to handle string with no limit? Just declaring char *str is no good, so what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inputs,count=0;
    char str[20];
    scanf("%d",&inputs);
    char *ptr;
    char *dummy;

    while(inputs-- >0)
    {
        scanf("%s",str);

        for(ptr=str; *ptr!='\0';ptr++)
        {
            for(dummy=ptr+1; *dummy != '\0';dummy++)
            {
                if( *ptr== *dummy)
                {
                    count=1;
                }
            }
            if(count == 1)
                break;
        }
        if(count>0)
        {
            printf("NOT UNIQUE");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("UNIQUE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what solution you gave, but the problem remains the same, it's giving output right after user types a string and hits enter, but I want the outputs like "Sample Input" and "Sample Output" or like -> Sample Input: 
 3
 DELHI
 london
 #include<iostream>

Sample Output: 
 UNIQUE
 NOT UNIQUE
 NOT UNIQUE

Comment: oh ok! I wrote this answer before your question is edited. From your code I see that you are trying to take input and print the output immediately. I have corrected the logic where you are trying to find the word is unique or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save stuff for later use, you must store it somewhere. The example below stores up to 10 lines in `buf` and then points `str` to the current line:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    /* for strlen */
#include <ctype.h>     /* for isspace */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int ninput = 0;
    char buf[10][100];      /* storage for 10 strings */
    char *str;              /* pointer to current string */
    int i;

    printf("Enter up to 10 strings, blank to and input:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int l;

        str = buf[i];

        /* read line and break on end-of-file (^D) */
        if (fgets(str, 100, stdin) == NULL) break;

        /* delete trailing newline & spaces */
        l = strlen(str);
        while (l > 0 && isspace(str[l - 1])) l--;
        str[l] = '\0';

        /* break loop on empty input */
        if (l == 0) break;
        ninput++;
    }

    printf("Your input:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ninput; i++) {
        str = buf[i];
        printf("[%d] '%s'\n", i + 1, str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the two separate loops for input and output.

I've also rejiggled your input. I'm not very fond of `fscanf`; I prefer to read input line-wise with `fgets` and then analyse the line with `strtok` or `sscanf`. The advantage over `fscanf` is that yout strings may contain white-space. The drawback is that you have a newline at the end which you usually don't want and have to "chomp".

If you want to allow for longer strings, you should use dynamic allocation with `malloc`, although I'm not sure if it is useful when reading user input from the console. Tackle that when you have understood the basics of fixed-size allocation on the stack.

Other people have already pointed you to the error in your check for uniqueness.